# Removing partition table

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

I have two machines:

- A mini-itx system I set up to act like a NAS with ubuntu 16.04, 2+ years old
- I micro-atx system I set up to act as an HTPC with Windows 10, just new

My NAS system has an ssd boot disk and a 2TB file disk. This question is about the 2TB hdd. The 2TB file disk has one single ext4 partition on the whole disk. Because the NAS is slow and barely capable of transcoding video's I wanted to double my new HTPC as a NAS. I was not sure if Windows would be able to read the ext4 partition but I figured I would just try.

So I tried and Windows was not able to read the disk, it just showed as unallocated diskspace. So I connected it back to my NAS to find out it does not work on it anymore either. I am not able to mount the 2TB disk.

When I do fdisk -l it shows as a Microsoft Reserved Partition:

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 1.8Tib, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: F7CB1168-49F7-4885-BFE2-EF9905099A86

Device    Start   End Sectors Size Type
/dev/sdc1    34 32767   32734  16M Microsoft reserved

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

I also used testdisk to scan my drive which took me 4 days. I scanned the drive, as recommended in the testdisk guide, as Intel EFI and also tried MBR but unfortunately both scans just showed rubbish. But then I thought, maybe I should scan as "None" partition table, as suggested when I start testdisk, so I did:

```
Disk /dev/sdc - 2000 GB / 1863 GiB - CHS 243201 255 63
Current partition structure:
     Partition                  Start        End    Size in sectors

   P ext4                     0   0  1 243201  80 63 3907029168 [data]
```

This is exactly what is on my disk, an ext4 partition covering the whole disk named "data".

My conclusion: When I formated the disk 2+ year ago I did it wrong but did not notice, which resulted in a disk without a partition table. When I connected it to my Windows machine it found no partition table and created a wrong one. So I think I need to delete the partition table. I did search online but there is no information mentioning ONLY removing the partition table, not the existing partitions.

Another option would maybe be to create a correct partition table myself to point at the existing ext4 partition.

My question: Is my conclusion right? And can you advise me on how to accomplish above tasks?

This is the fstab rule I mounted the 2TB disk with before:

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/cfcf09cb-55fc-40a7-b0b3-afd4d809bb09 /mnt/cfcf09cb-55fc-40a7-b0b3-afd4d809bb09 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

EDIT 1: 
Due to experimentation and removal of other drives the drive is named sdb from now on.

I went ahead and used gdisk to remove my partition table. fdisk -l now shows:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 1,8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

Testdisk still gives me the same result. I tried just mounting sdb:

```
mount -t ext4 /dev/sdb /media/data

mount: /media/data: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

EDIT 2: So I googled the above error en found that I needed to

```
e2fsck -f /dev/sdb
```

Which did a check, changed a lot and now I am able to mount en browse my data!

Comment: I am no expert, but it looks like Windows replaced the MBR in your data disk with GPT when you took it out of the Ubuntu machine and attached it to the Windows machine. I assume you are running Windows 8 or higher in UEFI mode.

Comment: If you formatted the drive, not a partition, then you do not have a partition to recover or connect to. You just need to create a new partition table & restore your data from your backups. And your write of partition table at beginning of drive overwrote the start of the drive and that data. You may be able to get some data with photorec, but now even mounting drive will be difficult.

Comment: I am indeed running windows 10 in UEFI mode. @oldfred you mean formatted the drive when I first started using it in my NAS? So it is not possible to point to the part where there should be an ext4 partition? I have backups of all important data but I also have music and movie data. The data is still on the drive, so I think I should be able to access it.

Comment: I'm no expert but it **seems** a "no-partition-table" partition table is OK https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/346826/323121 testdisk even detects it. All you need to do is ask testdisk to write it out https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step At YOUR RISK of course 

Comment: @Rusi that's also what I found. Unfortunately testdisk says: "Write isn't available because the partition table type "None" has been selected.". Thus I think I need to just delete the partition table.  What if I just delete the Microsoft Reserved Partition with parted so the partition table is empty? I also tried mounting just "/dev/sdc" but that says mount: "/dev/sdc is already mounted or /media/data busy". I umounted the whole drive with no result. I also tried other mount locations with the same message.

Comment: /media/data is mounted. So what do you see if you cd into it?

Comment: @Rusi I fixed it. Thank you for your help! I will post a complete solution write up as an answer.